# Python: scikit-learn isomap results seem random, but no possibility to set random_state

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using Isomap from scikit-learn manifold learning. I reduce to two dimension, and observe that with every run of the algorthm on the same data set without any changes the resulting vectors change. I assume there are some random numbers used in the algorithm, but there is no way to set a seed. Random_state is not a variable to pass in Isomap. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mind showing a code example you've been testing? As far as I know, there is no randomness in isomap. So allow me to guess that the randomness comes from your data generation.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I produced an easy example and there is no Variation in the result:  

`import numpy as np  
from sklearn import manifold  
np.random.seed(4)  
data = np.random.randn(100,10)  
iso=manifold.Isomap(n_components=2)  
result = iso.fit_transform(data)`

Comment: I checked my original code, and still observe strange behaviour. Executing these 2 lines repeatedly results in a change in sign of some components of the isomap result. data is a 200 by 200 symmetric matrix:  `isomapping = manifold.Isomap()    
result = isomapping.fit_transform(data)`

Comment: I see what you mean by random. I'll explain in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The random you've seen is about the sign of your result. The sign is not (in my opinion) 100% random. Signs within each component are consistent so that the relative relation is consistent in your result. Signs between components are random. In other words, which component got multiplied by `-1` or `1` are random. This behavior comes from the `KernelPCA` function used by `Isomap` when the `arpack` kernel is used.

To give you a solution first, you can use `eigen_solver='dense'` when using `Isomap`. That may slow down your algorithm but should remove this randomness. I know this explanation above might be confusing. Let me give more details and show this by plot.

First, what is a visualized consequence of the "sign randomness"? Using the following code (modified from [this official example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/manifold/plot_lle_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-manifold-plot-lle-digits-py)) with `eigen_solver = 'arpack'`, you can see two `fit_transform` using the same `Isomap` class may (or may not) give you different results. However, as you can see in the plot, the relative location maintains. It's just the whole plot getting flipped. If you use `eigen_solver='dense'` and run the code multiple times, you won't see this randomness:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import offsetbox
from sklearn import (manifold, datasets, decomposition, ensemble,
                     discriminant_analysis, random_projection)

digits = datasets.load_digits(n_class=6)
X = digits.data
y = digits.target
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
n_neighbors = 30

def plot_embedding(X, ax, title=None):
    x_min, x_max = np.min(X, 0), np.max(X, 0)
    X = (X - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        ax.text(X[i, 0], X[i, 1], str(digits.target[i]),
                 color=plt.cm.Set1(y[i] / 10.),
                 fontdict={'weight': 'bold', 'size': 9})

eigen_solver = 'arpack'
#eigen_solver = 'dense'
iso = manifold.Isomap(n_neighbors, n_components=2, eigen_solver=eigen_solver)
X_iso1 = iso.fit_transform(X)
X_iso2 = iso.fit_transform(X)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
plot_embedding(X_iso1, ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
plot_embedding(X_iso2, ax2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Secondly, is there a way to set a seed to "stabilize" the random state? No, there is currently no way to set a seed for `KernelPCA` from `Isomap`. With [`KernelPCA`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA), however, there is a kwarg `random_state` which is "A pseudo random number generator used for the initialization of the residuals when eigen_solver == ‘arpack’". Play with the following code (modified from [this official test code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/tests/test_kernel_pca.py#L142-L165)) and you can see this randomness is gone (blue dots cover red dots) even with `eigen_solver = 'arpack'`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA

X_fit = np.random.rand(100, 4)
X = np.dot(X_fit, X_fit.T)

eigen_solver = 'arpack'
#eigen_solver = 'dense'
#random_state = None
random_state = 0
kpca = KernelPCA(n_components=2, kernel='precomputed', 
                 eigen_solver=eigen_solver, random_state=random_state)
X_kpca1 = kpca.fit_transform(X)
X_kpca2 = kpca.fit_transform(X)

plt.plot(X_kpca1[:,0], X_kpca1[:,1], 'ro')
plt.plot(X_kpca2[:,0], X_kpca2[:,1], 'bo')

plt.show()
```

[image]